# Using switches inside static tableview

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift, uiswitch

I have a static tableview for settings. I have switches inside this tableview. But I don't know how to access to switches from code. I mean how can I get the switch on/off status in code ?

View:

[image]

I have one view controller for settings but I couldn't drag from switches to view controller. I guess i have to drag to tableview controller. But I don't know how to do this. Can somebody show me a roadmap for this operation ?

This is my storyboard:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can link outlets only with class, which is set as parent in storyboard. So you should create new class MyTableViewController, set it as parent for your storyboard TableViewController and after that you'll be able to drag your switches and connect them.

Comment: But I need that outles inside view controller. How can I do that ?

Comment: There is no way to do it, the only way to access it from other viewController is to have MyTableViewController reference there, but it seems pointless because you can't interact them. You should work with UI elements only inside their parent controller.

Comment: Ok,could you show me a little example for this operation ?

Comment: If you have tree like ViewController->TableViewController, you should create MyTableViewController. Or kick of ViewController and use TableViewController directly.

Comment: Yes, but You still have to create MyTableViewController for TableViewController scene and manage switches there. You can't connect it to Ayarlar scene. OR you can just make your Alarlar controller (actual class inside the project) subclass of TableViewController and set it as parent to TableViewController scene and delete Ayarlar scene from storyboard. Maybe I'm described a bit muddling: the goal is no to use ViewController->Segue->TableViewController, but just use TableViewController.

Answer (score 2):

Add an `IBOutlet` to each switch and check the `isOn` property.

Comment: To where ? View controller or table view controller ?